# Problem with generic base class and not-generic child class in an interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

I'm having some trouble with implementing an interface on a "non-generic" child class, that derives from a generic base class:

```
    public class Parent<T> where T : struct, Enum
    {
    }

    public class Child : Parent<MyEnum>
    {
    }

    interface ISomeInterface<T> where T : struct, Enum
    {
        void SomeMethod(Parent<T> parent);
    }

    class SomeClass : ISomeInterface<MyEnum>
    {
        public void SomeMethod(Child child)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

It won't compile because "SomeClass does not implement the interface..."

When I change to

```
   public void SomeMethod(Parent<MyEnum> child)
```

everything is fine.

But shouldn't the first code also work since `Child` actually is `Parent<MyEnum>` ?

Comment: Hint: what would you expect `new SomeClass().SomeMethod(new Parent<MyEnum>())` to do? That's passing a `Parent<MyEnum>` argument, but your parameter is of type `Child`.

Comment: To put it another way, leaving generics aside, if an interface has `void SomeMethod(object obj)` would you expect to be able to implement that using `void SomeMethod(string text)`? It's really the same thing here.

Comment: Tanks a lot! That helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are assuming inheritance in implementing an interface method works the same as calling a method with parent class. They are different.